# laravel do not return call stack on error

Tags: php, laravel, rest, exception

For example in my REST Json API: When I call a route with route model binding and pass an invalid id I get:

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\User].",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "D:\\allianz\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
    "line": 199,
    "trace": [
        { ...
```

However I would prefer not to show this to the API consumer. (Or just the message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is you APP_ENV variable set at?  I believe the call stack won't be returned when it's in production.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. However it depends on APP_DEBUG rather than APP_ENV

Answer (score 1):

You can always catch the exception in the App\Exceptions\Handler.php

Import the exception into the class using the following:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

and in the render method, add

```
if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Record not found', //or modify it to display whatever message you want here
    ], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked in the last century, I like to leave an answer for Laravel 9.7.0.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322235/3469861) shows how to globally set how unhandled exceptions should be rendered in http-responses.

I changed the code a bit to return the exception-info without a stack-trace:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, $request) {
        $env = config("app.env");

        $msg = $e->getMessage() . " in file '" . $e->getFile() . "' on line '" . $e->getLine() . "'";

        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            if (strcmp($env, "debug") == 0) {
                return response()->make($msg.$e->getTraceAsString(), 500);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => $msg
                ], 500);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So if I set `APP_ENV=debug` in the .env-file the stacktrace will be added to the repsonse text-message. It's text because I did not test how the stacktrace would mess with the consumers json interpreter. If APP_ENV != debug, the response is a json object with a message-value containing the message, file and linenumber.