# How to add status in default response passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am developing and application in web as well as App. For App's API I have use Passport in laravel. Using passport i can create token and using that token I verify user for other api access. But if token in invalid then it return Error message like "Unauthorized" without any status. Can  any one tell me what to do if i want to add error status like 401 with message "Unauthorized" . Where I have to change in code so that my web code is not affect. I want json response like below with 2 fields in json.

status:401
message:Unauthorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new exception handler middleware to catch these requests and modify the response it returns.

Example:

```
class oAuthExceptionHandler {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        try {
            $response = $next($request);

            if (isset($response->exception) && $response->exception) {
                throw $response->exception;
            }

            return $response;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(array(
                'result' => 0,
                'msg' => $e->getMessage(),
            ), 401);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`, name your middleware and add it into your api group:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'oauth_exception' => oAuthExceptionHandler::class,
    ...
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ...

    'api' => [
        'oauth_exception',
        ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: I have try your code but still get only 
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
I want response like
{
   "status":"401"
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}

Comment: Sorry there was my mistake. Now its work fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the api exception and format its response in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

Here is the link that you can follow

[Laravel API, how to properly handle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065170/laravel-api-how-to-properly-handle-errors)