# Handler not used when controller function is triggered

Tags: laravel, exception, httpresponse

I'm missing something in my code and I would like to know where is the problem. I want to test if my API responses can handle exceptions but they only return 500 if the user is unauthorized.

I did look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065170/laravel-api-how-to-properly-handle-errors), in my case I would get a 401 error when I call this route.

Controller

```
   public function index()
    {
        try{
            return response()->json(Product::orderByDesc('updated_at')->get(), 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new HttpException(401, $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Arguments are ordered incorrectly. Should be `HttpException($e->getMessage(), 401)`.

Comment: Yes but it still returns 500

Comment: check `storage/logs/laravel.log` there should be written where is error triggered.

Comment: To authorize data, what do you use? Are you using middleware, policy, or gate? And I think it would be better if you also tell us the Laravel version you are using.

Comment: I use laravel 8.83.0 and I have a middleware to check if the JWT is in the header of each request