# Getting GET error while sending POST request to the POST route in Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

Locally project runs fine. On the server getting this error while sending POST request to the POST route in Laravel 9 API.

```
"message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."
```

My route from the api.php routes file:

```
Route::post('/userdata/create', [UserDataController::class, 'createAccount']);
```

My route from the routes list (from **php artisan route:list**):

```
POST       api/v1/userdata/create .......... Api\V1\UserDataController@createAccount
```

Tried:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
```

Didn't fixed it yet.

Comment: post your blade code

Comment: It's an API route, there is no Blade code.

Comment: then your api send get request instead of post request.

Comment: no, i'm sending requests through Postman software, using POST method. And also from the mobile app, also using POST method.

Comment: can you provide us codes in your routes file ?

Comment: it's provided: - 

 "Route::post('/userdata/create', [UserDataController::class, 'createAccount']);" 

 - and there is no other route with the same URI and GET method defined.

Comment: What is the url you send your requests in Postman?

Comment: Can't share the URL, but here's Postman result: https://i.imgur.com/VWXAFbe.png It's visible here that request was sent using POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to that problem was actually very simple:

I needed to send POST request to "https" url, and i was sending it to "http" url.

Still strange that server was complaining that GET method is used...

Answer (score 4):

It happens cause you have **forced** your domain to **HTTPS** redirect and you are trying to use it as **HTTP**.
Your domain settings redirect your request to **HTTPS** but not to **POST** method.

- If you look for postman logs/console you will find redirection of **HTTP** POST request to **HTTPS** GET request

[image]

- Hence Error response by your server of

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me recently where I was using .com instead of .net

Answer (score 0):

that happen because laravel cannot return the error.

**SOLUTION 1 :**

you can use this inside your API post function :

```
try{
   // example we have name field
   $request->validate([
      'name' => ['required','string','max:255']
   ]);
   
   User::create([
      'name' => $request->name
   ]);

   return 'registered';
     
}catch(Exception $error){
   
   // your error from validation will appear here
   // dd($error->validator->messages());
   
}
```

**SOLUTION 2 :**

as alternative :
I found another method here at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065170/laravel-api-how-to-properly-handle-errors)